# Why does it say MailingPostalCode doesn't exist?

Tags: validation-rule

[image]

It keeps saying that MailingPostalCode doesn't exist.
It also says that Account.Id doesn't exist, as well as <> and Account.
Someone please help!!!

Comment: Hi @Nebula, could you please add what is the requirement? And can you double-check check whether  MailingPostalCode is exist or not?

Comment: 'MailingPostalCode' field exists on [contact](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contact.htm) not on account.  You can create above validation on contact **AND( NOT(ISBLANK(AccountId)), MailingPostalCode != Account.ShippingPostalCode )**

Comment: What is the object you are building this rule on?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting this error is because field **MailingPostalCode** does not exist on **Account object**

***You need to create the validation rule on Contact Object.***

```
AND( 
NOT( ISBLANK( AccountId ) ), 
MailingPostalCode <> Account.ShippingPostalCode 
)
```

Check Fields available on contact Object

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_Contact.htm

Check Fields available on Account Object

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_Account.htm